# Apply function to multiple columns, indexing a previous result

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a formula, mean, to each column. Then I'd like to use that result in another formula, stdev, applied to each column. I've managed to write the function for column A01, but need to work out how to apply both to all columns.

```
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15), A01 = c(6485,35,132), A02 = c(0,42,56))

htmat <- data.matrix(data)

mean <- crossprod(htmat$A01, htmat$CAG) / colSums(htmat$A01)


stdev <- sqrt((sum((htmat$A01) ^2 * htmat$A01 / colSums(htmat$A01) - mean ^2) * colSums(htmat$A01) / (colSums(htmat$A01) -1)
```

Comment: Can you not use built in functions `mean` and `sd`? `lapply(data, mean)` and `lapply(data, sd)`?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. It's not simply a case of running mean and sd on a column as cols A01 and A02 are frequency distributions of column CAG. i.e. 6485 counts of 13 CAGs, 35 counts of 14 CAGs etc. Need to then work out the mean number of CAGs for that column, same for sd

Comment: I think I follow; `data` is a cross-tab of frequencies? In which case, it's almost always better to work with long data in R, so I'd replicate it out: `cag = rep(data$CAG, data$A01)` which gives you a vector you can take the `mean()` and `sd()` of?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. I've tried and got it working for one column, A01.

Comment: data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15), A01 = c(6485,35,132), A02 = c(0,42,56))
print(data)

Comment: cag = rep(data$CAG, data$A01)
print(cag)

Comment: mean <- mean(cag)
print(mean)

Comment: But not sure how to apply to all columns

Comment: Edit and update your question rather than add lots of comments; it makes it harder to see what you've tried and still need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, long-format data is almost always better to work with. To solve this we can replicate out a data set, using `A01` as an example:

```
cag = rep(data$CAG, data$A01)
```

You can then take the `mean()` and `sd()` from this vector. To loop over all columns (except `CAG`) in `data` we can use `lapply()`:

```
lapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)

  list(
    mean = mean(data_e),
    sd   = sd(data_e)
  )
})
```

This loops over each column, and for each iteration is replicates it out and stores it as a vector, `data_e` (extracted). The loop then returns a list including the mean and standard deviation of `data_e`.

You can assign the results to a new object and extract values with `$` or `[]` as normal, for example:

```
dat <- lapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)

  list(
    mean = mean(data_e),
    sd   = sd(data_e)
  )
})

dat$A01$mean
```

You can see what's available in `dat` with `str(dat)`.

## Edit: re-create data frame with `mean` and `sd` columns

To recreate a data frame, rather than a list of lists, return a `data.frame` rather than a `list` in the first `lapply()` loop:

```
dat <- lapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)
  data.frame(
    mean = mean(data_e),
    sd   = sd(data_e)
  )
})
```

This returns a list of data frames, which we can collapse into one data frame with `do.call(rbind, ...)`:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, dat)
dat
#          mean        sd
#  A01 13.04495 0.2874512
#  A02 14.57143 0.4974160
```

`A01` and `A02` are `row.names()`, which you can explicitly assign to an id variable with `dat$id <- row.names(dat)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm outputting these results to a table along with other stats. The other stats output as vectors with one value for each column (A01, A02 etc.). Is it possible to output the mean and sd as vectors that I can insert into this table too?      results <- data.frame(samples, sumheight, mean, mode)

Comment: I've been trying to turn the rep() output into columns that I can then use to generate mean and sd vectors, but not sure if I'm going along the right route.     data[,2:ncol(data)] <- c(rep(data[,1], data[,2:ncol(data)]))

Comment: Where I'm getting a little lost in your explanation is "You can save the results to a new object and extract values with $ or [] as normal." None of the values appear to be available after function has run

Comment: @Mike I've edited my question to explain what I mean

Comment: Great, thanks. It looks to be giving pretty much what I need now. I've made it output a data.frame() rather than list(). Could I please ask if you know how to invert the output so that A01, A01 etc are rows and mean, mode etc are columns?

Comment: I've tried transposing the output with t(dat), then dat$mean, but the result comes out as 'NULL'

Comment: $mean
[1] 13.04495

$sd
[1] 0.2874512

Comment: @Mike I've updated the answer to restructure the output.